# Selecting Nodes under two different conditions in XPath

Tags: xpath, conditional-statements, intersect

I'm working on a Query in XPath and somehow I just can't get it to work.
I've got more cars in my "garage" of course, but to solve the problem, the two Nodes will do it:

```
<garage>
<car>
     <data>
        <brand name="Mazda" model="MX5"></brand>
        <country>Japan</country>
        <ctype>Cabriolet</ctype>
        <motor fueltype="Super">
            <ps>146</ps>
            <kw>107</kw> 
            <umin>5000</umin>
        </motor>
        <price>22000</price>
     </data>
</car>


<car>
    <data>
        <brand name="Audi" model="RS6"></brand>
        <country>Germany</country>
        <ctype>Limousine</ctype>
        <motor fueltype="Super">
            <ps>580</ps>
            <kw>426</kw> 
            <umin>6250</umin>
        </motor>
        <price>108000</price>
     </data>
</car>
</garage>
```

I want to count all cars, that are from japan AND got at least 100 ps (ps means horsepower in german). In the example above the result should be 1, because only the mx5 matches both conditions. I tried "and", I tried "intersect" and now I'm out. Could someone help me out, PLEASE!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
/garage/car[data/country = 'Japan' and data/motor/ps >= 100]
```

or:

```
/garage/car[data/country = 'Japan'][data/motor/ps >= 100]
```

or:

```
/garage/car[data[country = 'Japan'][motor/ps >= 100]]
```

The above are all equivalent. To get the count, wrap any of the above with `count(...)`.

Comment: It worked - all three of them. Those f.... brackets. I would never have figured it out. Thank you very very much !